# JavaScript Filter and Reduce to concatenate strings

Tags: javascript

Im trying to filter and reduce a list of objects to tell me who is in each group, Ive just started learning map and reduce so I may be doing this the  wrong way:

```js
data = [  { name: 'Tom', group: 1, },
{ name: 'Jim', group: 2, },
{ name: 'Red', group: 1, },
{ name: 'Sue', group: 2, },
{ name: 'Max', group: 3, },
{ name: 'Sam', group: 2, },
];

let crew = data.filter(person => {
 return person.group == 2;
}).reduce( (prevVal,currVal,idx) => {
 return idx == 1 ? prevVal.name + ',' + currVal.name : prevVal + ',' + currVal.name;
});

console.log(crew + " = Group 2");
```

I need a generic way of achieving the following output as I don't know how many groups there are:

```
Tom,Red = Group 1
Jim,Sue,Sam = Group 2
Max = Group 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `.filter` part, and reduce into an object indexed by group - then, you can iterate over the object's entries:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'Tom', group: 1, },
  { name: 'Jim', group: 2, },
  { name: 'Red', group: 1, },
  { name: 'Sue', group: 2, },
  { name: 'Max', group: 3, },
  { name: 'Sam', group: 2, },
];
const crew = Object.entries(
  data.reduce((a, { name, group }) => {
    if (!a[group]) a[group] = [];
    a[group].push(name);
    return a;
  }, {})
).map(([group, names]) => names.join(',') + ' = Group ' + group);
console.log(crew);
```

(As a side note - *any* `.filter` followed by `.reduce` can be turned into a single `.reduce`, if you wish reduce the total number of iterations over the input required - simply test the filter condition before carrying out the reduce action.)

Comment: You can also simplify your reduce like this..
data.reduce((acc, { group, name }) => ({ ...acc, [group]: (acc[group] || []).concat(name) }), {});

Comment: That method requires creating a separate object for each iteration, and isn't entirely readable IMO - I prefer using just one object.

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve what you're trying to do with just one method: `Array.prototype.reduce`. In my code below, I just created a map object (the `accum` parameter) - each property is an array that stores the members of that group:

```js
const data = [{
    name: 'Tom',
    group: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Jim',
    group: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'Red',
    group: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Sue',
    group: 2,
  },
  {
    name: 'Max',
    group: 3,
  },
  {
    name: 'Sam',
    group: 2,
  },
];

//Use reduce to keep a map of distinct groups
//Each group will be an array of names
const groups = data.reduce((accum, el) => {
  //If your map already contains the group array, just add the user
  if (accum[el.group]) {
    accum[el.group].push(el.name);
  }
  //If not, create the array with the user name included
  else {
    accum[el.group] = [el.name]
  }

  return accum;
}, {})

Object.entries(groups).forEach(group => {
  const [key, value] = group;
  console.log(`Group ${key} members: ${value}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `reduce` to group the objects.

```js
let data = [  { name: 'Tom', group: 1, },{ name: 'Jim', group: 2, },{ name: 'Red', group: 1, },{ name: 'Sue', group: 2, },{ name: 'Max', group: 3, },{ name: 'Sam', group: 2, }],
    prefix = 'Group',    
    result = data.reduce((a, {name, group}) => {
      let key  = [prefix, group].join('');
      (a[key] || (a[key] = [])).push(name);      
      return a;
    }, Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```